# Can I apply a face to an optional group?

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

When I try to execute the following, font-lock fails abruptly after it matches the first group.  A little bit of debugging with the neat tool `font-lock-studio` and I realized that `font-lock` is upset that it can't find group `2`.  How can I tell it not to freak out?

```lisp
(define-derived-mode expl3-mode prog-mode
  "expl3"
  "Mode for editing expl3 source code."

  (setq font-lock-set-defaults nil)
  (font-lock-set-defaults)
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   `((,(rx (* whitespace)
           (group (+ (any alnum "-")))
           (* whitespace)
           (optional "/" (* whitespace)
                     (group (+ (any alnum "_"))))      ; note
           (+ whitespace)
           (group "." (+ (any alpha)) (optional "_"))
           (group (optional (any alpha) (+ (any alpha "_"))))
           (group ":" (* (any "nNpTFwcVvxofD"))))
      (1 font-lock-variable-name-face t)
      (2 font-lock-variable-name-face t)               ; the optional group
      (3 font-lock-type-face t)
      (4 font-lock-function-name-face t)
      (5 font-lock-keyword-face t)))))
```

#### Test string

```
test-key .tl_set:N ...
with / grouping .code:n ...
```

Comment: It looks like a typo in the regexp, try: `(optional "/" (* whitespace) (group (+ (any alnum "_"))))`.

Comment: @Lindydancer Doh! :) That was it precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use the `LAXMATCH` flag for the second group:

```
(2 font-lock-variable-name-face t t)
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of situations the LAXMATCH flag is intended for.

Comment: @Lindydancer It's still upsetting that the regex breaks after setting it.

Comment: If you step in font-lock-studio, you'll see that the `with /`part simply isn't included in the match at all (you'll see this as it's not highlighted with a background color like the rest of the line is). I would revise the regexp to ensure that it matches, place the point at the beginning of `when`, use `looking-at` and the beginning of the regexp, then add more and more of it until it longer returns true, then you know which part of the regexp caused it to fail to match.